# How fix "Failed to import index-pattern"

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, metricbeat

When i`m try setup metricbeat dashboard i get error.

i run this command:

```
metricbeat setup --dashboards
```

and got this error:

```
     metricbeat setup --dashboards
    Loading dashboards (Kibana must be running and reachable)
    Exiting: Failed to import index-pattern: Failed to load directory 
    /usr/share/metricbeat/kibana/6/index-pattern:
      error loading /usr/share/metricbeat/kibana/6/index- 
   pattern/metricbeat.json: blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow 
    delete (api)];. Response: {"objects":[{"id":"metricbeat-*","type":"index- 
   pattern","error":{"message":"blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / 
    allow delete (api)];"}}]}
```

i try this :

```
https://benjaminknofe.com/blog/2017/12/23/forbidden-12-index-read-only-allow-delete-api-read-only-elasticsearch-indices/

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/forbidden-12-index-read-only-allow-delete-api/110282
```

it doesnt help me.
in my hard drive im got more then 40% free space
i restart elastic, kibana, metricbeat
nothing help.
all elastick stack installed on one server and metricbeat.
also i`m try remove index metricbeat* - not help 
pls help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Kibana has some problems with its storage, it changes its config to read-only mode automatically.

You should change the block "*read_only_allow_delete*" from "true" to "false".

You can check it by using the following command:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/.kibana/_settings'
```

Note: If it isn't a local machine, you must change "localhost" to your IP address or the resolved hostname.

There are two ways to fix it, via Kibana dashboard and by using cURL.

**Via Kibana Dashboard**

Go to Kibana dashboard, open Dev Tools, add the block of code which you can see below, and then push the "Run" button

```
PUT .kibana/_settings
{
"index": {
"blocks": {
"read_only_allow_delete": "false"
}
}
}
```

**Via cURL**

you should just execute the command below:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/.kibana/_settings" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
"index": {
"blocks": {
"read_only_allow_delete": "false"
}
}
}'
```

Good luck!